# Macro copy array of worksheets returns 1004 Copy method of Sheets class failed

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy

I've searched and found posts that are similar to this but I can't seem to find a solution that will get this one to work consistently.  Here's the overview:

1. Using MS Excel 2003, master template runs through list of customers, calculating a package of 13 XLS tabs.
2. Each set of tabs is copied and saved to files for each customer.
3. Usually, it works just fine.  But every 3-5 weeks, the process stops right before it's about to save a customer's file.
4. Error code is: 1004 Copy method of Sheets class failed

Additional note: Sometimes, if the current version won't work, rolling back to an earlier copy (say, from 6 weeks ago) will get it to run.  However, running that rolled back version on a subsequent run, will sometimes result in the same error.

========== ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========

SaveIt:
ActiveWorkbook.Save

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(Array("Monthly Values", "Daily Values", "Summary", _
    "Dashboard", "Product Summary", _
    "Customer Lookup", "Sales by Customer", "Sales by Customer Hotlist", _
    "Item Sales by Customer", "Item Sales by Cust Hotlist", _
    "Showroom Report", "New Accounts", "Contact Info")).Copy
```

*The error occurs on the "Sheets(Array..." command.
Beyond this point, the sheet goes on to copy and paste as values and format and such.*

```
Sheets(Array("Summary", "Product Summary")).Select

Sheets("Summary").Activate
```

========== ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========

Running in MS Excel 2003 SP3, Windows 7 Professional SP1.